# Post to Group in Workplace by Facebook using custom integration / Graph API

Tags: facebook-workplace, xmatters

Apologies - a total noob here. I am trying my best to research how to create a custom integration for Workplace by Facebook, so we can use one of our other tools, xMatters, to post messages to a group in Workplace.

I have been trying to find similar posts to help me learn how to do exactly that, but I haven't been to find one yet. I accept that maybe this is because it's just so basic.

Does anyone have any examples for what a working post to Workplace, that results in a message being posted on a Workplace group, would look like?

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a Workplace admin, you can create a new custom integration from the Admin Panel and getting the token that you can use to post in a group.

If you are an admin of a group, you can go in the integrations tab and click on "Create publishing BOT". You will have, in this case, an access token that can be used only in that group.

The post created by the bot looks like a common post, but you will see "BOT" near the name of the user or integration which posts

Comment: Thanks Francesca, this is exactly what I did in the end! I did it about a day before your post, and can confirm it works perfectly.